# Removing all tags except a few whitelisted ones with a regular expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a text with some HTML-like tags, which I would like to remove. I only want to allow about a dozen whitelisted tags, like <b> or <i>. I can't use PHP's strip tags, as I need a more general solution using regular expressions (as some of my other tags use different conventions, for example [tag] instead of <tag>). How do achieve this effect?

The regular expression I use right now is:

```
return preg_replace('/ \<[^\>]+\>/', '', $text);
```

How should I change it to exclude the tags I mentioned? I looked through similar questions but they don't provide a solution to the specific problem I mentioned here.

Comment: How will you account for things like this in your page: `<!-- < -->`

Comment: I'd point you at the definitive HTML v.s. regex post on SO, but it's redundant - no matter how you build your regex, someone'll manage to come up with some hideous monstrosity that'll let a malicious tag leak through.

Comment: [how have you not seen this post?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Don't use regex. Don't do it.

Comment: @zzzzBov: Posting that link is [not often helpful](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73133/regex-and-html-the-long-tail-annoys-me), and also quite incorrect when there was neither a question about *parsing* nor nested xhtml.

Comment: @Mark: That is not true. It’s just that it takes mastery of regexes to a level unlikely in anyone asking the question. Certainly I can do so, but I seldom advise others to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question anyway, you could use an assertion `(?!..)` to exclue things from matching:

```
preg_replace('#<(?!/?(a|b|i|div)\b)[^>]+>#'
```

But take in mind that this is not a very reliable approach. Filtering tag names is the easy part. For a complete sanitization you'd have to clean up attributes, where it becomes complicated. Try HTMLPurifier, which already contains heaps of regular expressions to do so.

Comment: I think assertions are the solution I was looking for. The tags don't have attributes as they are all under my control.

Comment: @pako: Sounds workable then. Don't forget the `\b`, like I did.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't use PHP's [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/strip_tags), use [**HTMLPurifier**](http://htmlpurifier.org/), which will allow you to implement all sorts of rules, safely.

Comment: I still believe strip_tags is the best method, but avoiding regex when html parsing is an even better one.

Comment: +1 for HTMLPurififer - just implemented in in a matter of minutes and am getting great functionality through it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$wl = '(?!(?:b|tr|td)\b)';   // whitelist in group

$rxtags = '
<
(?:
    (?:
       (?:
           (?:' ."$wl". 'script|' ."$wl". 'style) \s*
         | (?:' ."$wl". 'script|' ."$wl". 'style) \s+ (?:".*?"|\'.*?\'|[^>]*?)+\s*
       )> .*? </(?:' ."$wl". 'script|' ."$wl". 'style)\s*
    )
 |
    (?:
        /?' ."$wl". '\w+\s*/?
      | '   ."$wl". '\w+\s+ (?:".*?"|\'.*?\'|[^>]*?)+\s*/?
      | !(?:DOCTYPE.*?|--.*?--)
    )
)
>';
```

`s/$rxtags//xsg`

`"/$rxtags/xs"`, modifiers: expanded, span, globally

And change `' . "$wl" . '` to `' + "$wl" + '` or however catenation is done in php.